# native insert query in hibernate + spring data

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data

I try to add the following code to a spring data jpa repository:

```
  @Query("insert into commit_activity_link (commit_id, activity_id) VALUES (?1, ?2)")
  void insertLinkToActivity(long commitId, long activityId);
```

But an app can't start with the exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: VALUES near line 1, column 59 [insert into commit_activity_link (commit_id, activity_id) VALUES (?1, ?2)]

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I had to add `nativeQuery = true` to `@Query`

```
@Query(value = "insert into commit_activity_link (commit_id, activity_id) VALUES (?1, ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use java object rather passing all parameters

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "insert into [xx_schema].[shipment_p] (gpn,qty,hscode,country_of_origin,created_date_time,shipment_id) "
            + "VALUES (:#{#sp.gpn},:#{#sp.qty},  :#{#sp.hscode} ,:#{#sp.countryOfOrigin}, :#{#sp.createdDateTime}, :#{#sp.id} )", nativeQuery = true)
    public void saveShipmentPRoducts(@Param("sp") ShipmentProducts sp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Transactional` and `@Modifying` along with `@Query` to insert or update data using `nativeQuery`.

```java
@Transactional 
@Modifying
@Query(value="insert into commit_activity_link (commit_id, activity_id) VALUES 
              (:commitId, :activityId)", nativeQuery=true)
void insertLinkToActivity(@Param("commitId") long commitId,
                          @Param("activityId") long activityId);
```

Comment: Why `@Transactional` and `@Modifying` are required? you can use nativeQueries withou them. Why are you assuming that is needed from the question?