# Native insert JPA Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities:

**Entity A**
ID
NAME

**Entity B**
ID
NAME

**Join Table A_B**
A_ID
B_ID

I'm trying to do an insert based off of the secondary unique attributes (names).  I want to avoid fetching each entity by their name and then saving (2 queries & 1 insert vs 1 insert). Effectively, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "INSERT INTO A_B(A_ID, B_ID) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM A WHERE NAME = ?), (SELECT ID FROM B WHERE NAME = ?))")
void addToJoinTable(String nameA, String nameB);
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844306/native-insert-query-in-hibernate-spring-data), but I'm getting exceptions because an insert doesn't return a result set. The post mentions setting nativeQuery to true would resolve the issue, but I've had no such luck...  Is there another & better way to do this?

**Disclaimer:** I am new to JPA, so this might be a stupid question...

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries

Comment: @JBNizet, yes, but what would be the query in this case? I get the modifying annotation, but what would be the query? Thanks!

Comment: You have the query in your question.

Comment: Ah, doh! Forgot to annotate for transactions.. thanks! If you want to copy your response into an answer I'll accept it.  Many thanks!!